# Nodejs handling uploaded files

Tags: javascript, node.js, drag-and-drop, axios

I made a web app where people upload their files with drag and drop. They make a post a request to send their file to the nodejs server.

```
  uploadLocalFilesToDrive(e) {
    var files = e.dataTransfer.files;
    axios.post('/api/uploadLocalFilesToDrive', files[0])
    .then(function (res) {
       console.log('upload done');
     })
}
```

The goal of the nodejs server now, is to save this file on the server hard disk. This is what I made to handle the above request :

```
  uploadLocalFilesToDrive: (req, res) => {
    for(var key in req.body){
      filesystem.writeFile('new file name', key, function (err) {
        console.log("It's saved"); 
      });
    }
  }
```

It seems to work well with text files, but whenever the user upload a .pdf for instance, then the pdf becomes corrupted. I have a feeling it's an issue because the axios post request sends only text to the nodejs server, but I'm not sure. Help would be appreciated !

Answer (score 1):

[Multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer) is the best solution for nodejs-expressjs file uploads. Try it